# Necromancy and nigromancy

Tags: etymology, political-correctness

Necromancy and nigromancy descibe the act of black magic/ spiritualism. It comes from Greek originally and laterly Latin, according to Wikipedia. The question is, is this the ancient source of the term used in modern times with a derogatory intent towards Afro American  slaves and their decendents? I stumbled across the word, and it would make sense that it is in our collective psyche after international witch hunts since before Roman times. This word meaning 'dead man' which conjures moral fear of 'black magic' links neatly with Niger/Nigerian to suit the context of slavery in America at the time. Surely? Please don't mock! Am no academic!

Comment: [*necromancy*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=necromancy) comes from the Greek word for *dead*, not the Latin word for *black*. I would avoid using *nigromancy*, as this is an archaic spelling that looks racist.

Comment: Look, if you will, at Wikipedia under necromancy.Surely, sir, words are not intrinsicly racist.

Comment: Etymology is about identifying how words came to be. Witch hunts are burned into our very souls. Words associated with them must drag forward, even unbeknownst?

Comment: If you take a look at [a simple Ngram](http://bit.ly/19FQ6gj), you'll see that _nigromancy_, although the historically earlier form in English, has basically flatlined against the etymologically less corrupted _necromancy_ for the past two centuries. Nobody says _nigromancy_, and it's not only because it sounds like a racist word: nobody used it back when being racist was par for the course, and words like _negro_ and _nigger_ were not generally offensive like they are now. (Also, what international witch hunts since before Roman times?!?)

Comment: Are you implying that racism towards black-skinned people existed  in Roman times? Not so much. There was a black Roman emperor, and in Roman times, blond hair and not black skin was the most likely indicator of slavery.

Comment: In terms of the European experience, keep in mind that "slave" is derived from "Slav", as in slavic. Until the transportation technology improved markedly and New World demand for slaves exploded, the exportation of slaves from Africa was quite low. In other words, until roughly 1500 slaves in Europe were predominantly Caucasian. Since the term necromancy predates this, there is no connection between "black-skinned" and "black magic". Other than the general concept of the color black, of course.

Comment: No, Peter Shaw, I am making an association between an ancient, almost primal fear of being associated with nigr (black magic/witches/spirits) 'Nigr' has roots in ancient Greek, as I understand. Also, the fear of being accused of being anything besides the accepted faith;ie Christianity, during the past 2000 years of necromancy/nigromancy or witch hunts has created a negative reaction to the term long before America was taken over by Europeans, let alone began the disgusting exploitation of humans, called slavery. The term already sent shivvers down our spines, inbuilt not consciously, hmmm?

Comment: @PeterShor These things tend to move around. The Nazi Bureau of Race Research bestowed the title of Honorary Aryans on the Japanese. And Hitler was even known to have muttered some gibberish about the Italians being *Mediterranean Aryans*. I think the Turks were also credited with some sort of ethnic status. I guess if he had found an ally in Central Africa, the inhabitants would have become *Black Aryans*.

Answer (score 5):

I am also not an academic, but I am fairly well-read, including occult studies, and other than in your OP, I have never encountered the term about which you ostensibly inquire.

Aside from mentioning *nigromancy* in association with *necromancy* /ˈnɛkrɵˌmænsi/ in its definition of the latter term, Wikipedia has little to say, mentioning only that according to,

> “Herbert Stanley Redgrove *necromancy* was one of three chief branches of medieval ceremonial magic, the others being black magic and white magic. [But] [t]his does not correspond to contemporary classifications, which often mistake "*nigromancy*" ("*black-knowledge*") with "*necromancy*" ("*death-knowledge*")” See Wikipedia [**LINK**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necromancy).

etymonline returns the following two brief results:

> **A.)** necromancy (n.) c.1300, nygromauncy, "divination by communication with the dead," from Old French nigromancie "magic, necromancy, witchcraft, sorcery," from Medieval Latin nigromantia (13c.), from Latin necromantia "divination from an exhumed corpse," from Greek nekromanteia, from nekros "dead body" (see necro-) + manteia "divination, oracle," from manteuesthai "to prophesy," from mantis "prophet" (see mania). Spelling influenced in Medieval Latin by niger "black," on notion of "black arts." Modern spelling is a mid-16c. correction. Related: Necromantic.
>
> **B.)** necromancer (n.) c.1300, from Old French nigromansere, from nigromancie (see necromancy).
> see etymonline [**LINK**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=necromancy&searchmode=nl)

So, in summation: **a)** The conflation of “*niger*” with “*necro*” is the result of an error which has long ago been amended; **b)** No relationship exists between the erroneous formulation *nigromancy* and the disparaging term later used to dehumanize African-Americans, past or present; **c)** The term *nigromancy* isn’t used in modern times as far as I am aware (*see* Janus Bahs Jacquet's Ngram link above in commentary to OP); **d)** *negromancy* does not translate as "dead man" but basically as "the act of prophecy *via* communion with the dead" (*necro* + *mancy*); and **e)** This question strikes me as disingenuous, as well as potentially divisive and incendiary, but because I value this community, I thought it prudent to respond emphatically in answer-form rather than in commentary.

Comment: No need for bolding your entire answer.

Comment: I put 2 and 2 together and made 22! Possibly. But this old and deep rooted fear perhaps has tarnished language's relationship to the river black. I was researching witchcraft and stumbled upon the word... The unspeakable words of society.

Comment: People are as sensitive today about the use of the unspeakable N word as they were in the witch hunts of Roman times. It isn't racist or evil to discuss origins of a word. That said, is anyone willing to consider the word nigromamcy in connection with the word negro or nigger? Couldn't it be?

Comment: I meant to write 'the colour black' previously, not the river black.

Comment: I will value this site too if the contributors discuss language without borders. Disingenuous, that is your opinion about my activity, is it relevant?

Comment: I've just encountered your commentary and am going to sleep, but when I've rested I will give you a reply. For now, know that I have not downvoted your OP.

Comment: Is necromancy/nigromancy the ancient source of the term used in modern times with a derogatory intent towards Afro American slaves and their decendents? Answer: No. I can reach that conclusion utilizing the same sources you, yourself, cited. What then, is the source of your uncertainty?

Comment: Does the root “negro” become applied to African-Americans? Answer: Yes. The word "negro" is used in the English-speaking world to refer to a person of black ancestry or appearance. Negro denotes "black" in Spanish and Portuguese, derived from the ancient Latin word, niger, "black", which itself is probably from a Proto-Indo-European root nek-, "to be dark", akin to nok-, "night". See Wikipedia [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negro)

Comment: "People are as sensitive today about the use of the unspeakable N word as they were in the witch hunts of Roman times. It isn't racist or evil to discuss origins of a word." People *are* sensitive to usage of the N-word and that sensitivity is generally a welcome change. That sensitivity is due to the fact that in the USA “negro” turned into “nigger” and no longer was understood to mean a dark-skinned human being but rather a species of sub-human animal unworthy of moral consideration, the results of this change in meaning was, and remains, catastrophic. Its toll in suffering, incalculable.

Comment: You say: "I will value this site too if the contributors discuss language without borders. Disingenuous, that is your opinion about my activity, is it relevant?" So far (I’m new to this forum, myself) I have found the community of users/moderators of ELU to be wide-open to any genuine questions concerning the English language. At the same time, you might be surprised by the level of intelligence, learning, and clarity of vision of the ELU community (I know I was, having stumbled upon the site in much the same manner that you say you encountered the word under discussion).

Comment: You might also be surprised to learn that, for whatever reasons, some people become registered users only to vent their spleens and foment controversy and discord by attempting to post clever questions they imagine pass undetected. Such attempts are rarely successful. The community tends to be vigilant about such things. I hope I am wrong about the purpose of your OP, and if so, again I offer my sincerest apologies. Peace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21303/discussion-between-carrie-and-little-eva).

Comment: @Carrie - so I went, I logged in, and I "binged" you ...?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it seems I don't qualify pointwise... Thank you for discussing this point with me thus far, though.

Comment: How many reps do you need?

Comment: @Carrie - you need 20 rep to chat - as of this writing, you have 21. Bing me later in the day. I'm going down now.

Comment: Will be occupied until Monday regrettably, but will ping you when I'm on!